# Select a class within an i tag that is within a p tag and add a class to the anchor tag within

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have to select all anchor tags on the page that have an i tag before it, which has the class pdf. Both the i tag and the anchor is within a p tag. And then add a class of pdf to the anchor tag.

I wrote this and it adds the class to the p tag. I just need get it to add it to the anchor tag instead:

```js
$("p>i").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("pdf")) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('pdf');
  }
});
```

```css
.pdf {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>
```

Comment: <p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; </i><a href="www.somesite.com</a></p>

Comment: [css adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing your code much, use `next()`:

```js
$("p>i").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("pdf")) {
    $(this).next().addClass('pdf');
  }
});
```

```css
.pdf {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>

<p><i>&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>

<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>
```

Better

```js
$("p>i.pdf").each(function() {
    $(this).next().addClass('pdf');
});
```

```css
.pdf {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>

<p><i>&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>

<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>
```

Comment: @Craig https://stackoverflow.com/a/60552601/295783 is a better CSS selector answer - I updated to a more direct selector too

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, all you need is `$("p i.pdf + a").addClass('pdf')`:

```js
$("p i.pdf + a").addClass('pdf')
```

```css
.pdf {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>
<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>
<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>
```

The selector `$("p i.pdf + a")` selects all anchors that are siblings of an i element with the class of pdf that are a descant of a paragraph, and adds the pdf class to them.

Comment: That is the better selector.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS selector `p>.pdf+a`:

```js
$('p>.pdf+a').addClass('testClass');
```

```css
.testClass {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>
<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>
<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>
<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>
<p><i class="pdf">&nbsp; nn</i> <a href="www.somesite.com">link</a></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did not work though. I wrote this and it adds the pdf class to the p tag. I just need it to add it to the anchor tag instead:     $("p>i").each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("pdf")) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('pdf');
        }
    });

Comment: Ok, I just didn't understand your question comment